# regular expression to get a matching word from a line

Tags: regex, tcl

I am reading a file with one line at a time. I would like to get the text after `BADCONFIGNAME=` and store them in a list.
For the below example : my list would look like `{gnd_PWELL____vdd_NWELL gnd_PWELL____vdd33}`

```
- NB= '7' / BADCONFIGNAME= 'gnd_PWELL____vdd_NWELL'                                      
   - comment= ''top2_pst'/'state1 ' |||| '6/gnd_PWELL/gnd_on/0.000000' '3/vdd_NWELL/ON/1.2''
   - comment= ''top2_pst'/'state2 ' |||| '6/gnd_PWELL/gnd_on/0.000000' '3/vdd_NWELL/ON/1.2''
- NB= '8' / BADCONFIGNAME= 'gnd_PWELL____vdd33'
```

Can you please help me in deriving the correct regexp to get the required data from each of the lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few possible ways to select those symbols, and as usual a regular expression isn't the best tool for the job. Still,

```
if {[regexp {BADCONFIGNAME.*'(\w+)'} $line -> symbol]} {
    lappend result $symbol
}
```

works for this particular set of lines.

Comment: It's quite difficult to come up with a better tool than a regular expression for parsing tasks (except for things that are more complex and which use REs as part of what they do, such as full parsers where REs are often used in the lexing stage), but writing a good RE is an art and **requires** knowledge of what the format of the input data really is.

Comment: @DonalFellows: Certainly! They are immensely useful, and an important thing to practise. But over-reliance on regexes can easily be harmful, especially when coupled with a lack of understanding of what a regex is and how it differs from a regular expression, and with a notion that parsing begins and ends with regexes. What I am saying is that while `regexp` might be the best tool for parsing e.g. `BADCONFIGNAME.*'(\w+)'`, it isn't the best tool for parsing the file content that the question hints at. I suspect this question will get "um that worked but now..." follow-ups.

Comment: And no matter how I rewrite I end up with something that looks arrogant and know-it-all-ish. I did not invent this craft, I learned it from others (you, for instance), and when I try to point things out it's not because I think I know better (except when I do *of course* ;) ), but because I know that I have stumbled on this exact block a few times in my past.